# No module in python

Tags: python, wikipedia

I am getting this warning. What should I do about it?

```
File "alexis.py", line 17, in <module>
    import wikipedia
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wikipedia'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try doing:
`pip install wikipedia`

Answer (score 1):

if you are using VS Code terminal try:

```
py -m pip install wikipedia
```